# JS Accordion - How to have the information displayed below taking up the width of the 2 boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get the information to display the entire width of both the buttons? I know it because the boxContent is inside the box close div but is there a way I can have the information expanded out of the div?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box close">
    <div class="boxHeader">Box</div>
    <div class="boxContent">
      This is my DIV element.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box close">
    <div class="boxHeader">Box</div>
    <div class="boxContent">
      This is my DIV element.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box close">
    <div class="boxHeader">Box</div>
    <div class="boxContent">
      This is my DIV element.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box close">
    <div class="boxHeader">Box</div>
    <div class="boxContent">
      This is my DIV element.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the link to my full code : https://jsfiddle.net/sxbby09/3kt84jzu/2/

This is the output that I am trying to get : https://jsfiddle.net/sxbby09/0z7vdkx1/3/

Also, how do I remove the scrolling once I click on the content?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, when a box is clicked, it will be having 100% width, and the rest of the boxes will be having 50% width, is that what you are expecting ?

Comment: @AbinThaha The output I want should look something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/sxbby09/0z7vdkx1/3/ . The information should take up the width of the 2 columns.